# How to use plotly.js to export a chart with no browser

Tags: javascript, charts, export, plotly

I am wondering wether it is possible to export a [plotly](https://plot.ly/javascript/) chart to an image without opening a browser.

This is because I am running a program that executes javascript but has no html interaction, just javascript and I can't open any external program, either.

I can, however, write the contents of a file, say a string, to a file (it is javascript with some additions), so if [plotly](https://plot.ly/javascript/) can give me the contents I can do the rest.

I have seen pages like [this](https://plot.ly/javascript/static-image-export/) that show how to do it in a browser, but that's not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Javascript outside of a browser env. you're running probably running your scripts with node, [which plotly supports](https://plot.ly/nodejs/getting-started/).

Also, I would recommend you check out [node streams a](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93)s a way of having your data write scripts. They have a neat little `pipe` feature which would let you bypass holding the plot in-memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
However, it's not node. It's a DSL that supports javascript as its main language.

Comment: @M.M so the DSL runs on its own engine? How does the JS eventually turn into bytecode?

Comment: I do not now! I work with it but i don't know how it is implemented. So far my solution is to write to an html template that only needs the data...